# Create a column that contains a unique ID in reverse order

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently creating a dataframe that is sorted by 'Highest Score' in descending order. Something along the lines of the following:

```
      Score 1    Score 2    Highest Score
0       10          8            18
1        7          5            12
2        4          4             8
3        5          0             5
4        1          1             2
```

The dataframe I'm currently working on has thousands of rows.

I am trying to create a new column "New_ID" which creates a unique value for each row but starting with the highest number at the top:

```
      Score 1    Score 2    Highest Score    New_ID
0       10          8            18             4
1        7          5            12             3
2        4          4             8             2
3        5          0             5             1
4        1          1             2             0
```

I was wondering if this is possible and if so, how to go about doing it. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: `df['New_ID'] = np.arange(len(df),0,-1) - 1`?

Comment: df.index[::-1] ?

Comment: I think OP is also asking how to [`sort`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html)

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang worked perfectly